# Go command returns not found but works in terminal

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am trying to remove a record from MongoDB using the following line of Go code:

`mg.collection.Remove(bson.M{"id": 1})` this command returns a not found error but the following piece of codes works without issue in the terminal and Robomongo:

`db.getCollection('main').remove({"id":1})`

What am I doing wrong in Go?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see more of your code but I think I know what you're trying to do. You can call `Remove` just on your `collection`.

So (err handling removed for brevity):

`session` being the session variable:

```
collection := session.DB("your_db_name").C("main")

err = collection.Remove(bson.M{"id":1})
```